# "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject" When Create GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a problem with thread.When I want set a GridView into a ListView as View in another thread.It display a message which said:

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

```
    // Create grid view
                GridView grid = new GridView();
                // Add column
                // Name
                grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileName"]);
                // Type
                grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileType"]);
                // Data Modified
                grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileDataModified"]);
                // Size
                grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileSize"]);
// Edit view
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ListViewOp.View = grid));
```

What am I doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says `Dependency Property and its corresponding binding have to be created on same thread`. It can't be set on different threads. Put the creation of grid on UI dispatcher too. Since your ListView `View` DP is created on UI thread, hence its source property i.e. `GridView` should also be on UI thread.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(delegate
   {
       GridView grid = new GridView();
       grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileName"]);
       grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileType"]);
       grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileDataModified"]);
       grid.Columns.Add((GridViewColumn)myresourcedictionary["gridDirFileSize"]);
       ListViewOp.View = grid
   }));
```